# (e)grep: accented characters not recognised as part of a word

Tags: unicode, utf-8, grep, locale, non-ascii-characters

I would like to use (e)grep to match a whole word using the `-w` switch. I've set the locale, but accented characters are being treated as word boundaries as in this example:

```
$ locale
LANG=es_VE.utf8
LC_CTYPE="es_VE.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_VE.utf8"
LC_TIME="es_VE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="es_VE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="es_VE.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_VE.utf8"
LC_ALL=es_VE.utf8

$ echo -e "cáñamo\namo" | egrep -w amo
cáñamo
amo
```

How can I find `amo` while ignoring `cáñamo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which code points count as a word-class character is not locale-dependent in Unicode, and `LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE` is always a word character.

Here’s an all-UTF8 workflow demonstrating searching for `amo` after a word boundary, and after a non-(word-boundary):

```
 $ perl -Mutf8 -CSDA  -e 'print "cáñamo\namo\n"' | 
   perl -Mutf8 -CSDA -ne 'print if /\bamo\b/'
 amo

 $ perl -Mutf8 -CSDA  -e 'print "cáñamo\namo\n"' | 
   perl -Mutf8 -CSDA -ne 'print if /\Bamo\b/'
 cáñamo
```

I cannot help but be amused by your choice of search strings.  Thanks for the chuckle.

Comment: I had no idea what the sample words meant. I was asking for a friend. It seems like perl is the only way to go when it comes to utf8.